# How do I create JQuery/CSS3 block transition effects?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

I've seen a number of examples of JQuery plugins that create slideshows with lots of different styles of effects when the images transition from one to another.

I have been playing with this over the last day or so, and have some nice working examples of a slideshow using JQuery and would like start to use some of the more exotic transitions rather than simple sliding images in a list from left to right, or fading one image out and another in.

I want to lean how to do this myself, rather than use plugins, and wondered if anyone has an simple example of how I would transition from one image to another and have a block effect (or other other fancy effects), where one image is replaced by another made up of smaller blocks that fade in etc?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried already something? Any code to share?

Comment: *"I want to lean how to do this myself,"* ah.. well then,  Asking for working code samples is not the right way. there are so many tutorials on css transitions out there. go through them, try something.

Comment: Like I said I have a couple of simple working examples that transition using simple fade and animate, but nothing "complicated" like blocks. I've already read through the w3Schools pages on CSS3 but this doesn't cover anything that's really technical, hence my posting here. I find the best way is to have a starting point and to expand. I had no starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/rigipe/5/edit)**

[image]

- create a stack of sibling div elements,
- depending on the current *counter* set the [image URL to all of them as `background-image`,
- calculate each element position and apply exactly the same *inverse (-)* [value to it's `background-position` property.
- Set as Gallery background the next image (will not be yet visible)
- Animate the Current stack of DIV with an effect (opacity0, top, left...)
- Now the gallery bg is visible, we need to create a new stack of DIVs with that same image.

```
var $gal   = $('#gallery');
var width  = $gal.outerWidth();
var height = $gal.outerHeight();
var img = [
  "1.jpg",
  "2.jpg",
  "3.jpg",
];
var n = img.length;
var c = 0;

// Effects:
var fx = [
  {top: -height},
  {opacity: 0},
  {top:  height},
  {left: -width}
];

// Random FX:
function randFX(){
  return fx[ Math.floor(Math.random()*fx.length) ];
}

// Preload all images:
for(var i=0; i<img.length; i++){
  var nImg = new Image();
  nImg.src = img[i];
}

// Creates a new set of 5 DIV:
function div5(){
  var w5 = width/5 ;
  for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    var div = $("<div />", {
      'class' : "div5",
      'style' : "background: url("+img[c]+") "+ (-w5*i) +"px 0"
    });
    $gal.append(div);
  }
}
div5();

// Animates current set
function animDiv5(){

  // Prepare next image as gallery normal background image
  $gal.css({background: "url("+ img[c] +")"});

  // Generate a random animation
  var animfx = randFX();  

  // Animate Current DIVs
  $("div", $gal).each(function(i){
    $(this).stop().delay(70*i).animate( animfx, function(){
      if(!$(this).next()[0]){ // Once all are animated...
         $gal.html(""); // Remove DIVs
         // The gallery BG was visible for a tily amount of time,
         // now cover it with the same image but again splitted in DIVs
         div5(); 
      }
    });
  });
}



// Do it!
$("button").click(function(){
    c = ++c % n; // Increment counter
    animDiv5();
});
```

In the code above you might want to make sure that there's no current animation running before allowing another *trigger*, I've shown you just the basic principle.
Also another way to make the same gallery work flawlessly is to use JS **only** to create DIV elements, calculate the BG positions and to trigger events,
while creating all the animations you want using **enhanced CSS3 transitions.**

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll have a play and will see how I get on.

Comment: @Karl you're welcome. If you have questions don't hesitate.